# BLOB data taking so much time to retrieve from DB using Ibatis

Tags: spring, oracle, blob, ibatis

I am using Spring framework and ibatis ORM in my project. I have a table where many images are been stored as BLOB data. In my application, while trying to retrieve BLOB data its taking so much time. Is there any way to optimize the time taking for retrieving BLOB data ?

Here's the mapper - from the OP's comment

```
<resultMap id="mainImageDetails" type="PGReport"> 
    <result property="mainImageArr" column="image_data" jdbcType="BLOB" /> 
</resultMap> 

<select id="imageDetails" parameterType="PGReport" resultMap="mainImageDetails">
    select a.image_data as mainImageArr FROM pg_main_image WHERE pg_uid = #{pgUid} 
</select>
```

mainImageArr is an byte[] in my pojo class PGReport

Comment: Can you define "so much time", put in some logs and provide stats on how many records in how much time and the average size of the blob

Comment: Hi 6ton, thanks for your reply. :-) my average file size is 800 kb and max size is 1 mb. It is taking nearly a minute to retrieve if the file size is more than 800 kb.

Comment: Please share code that you using to read the blob (xml mapping, typehandler if any)

Comment: <resultMap id="mainImageDetails"
  type="PGReport">
  <result property="mainImageArr" column="image_data" jdbcType="BLOB" />
</resultMap>
<select id="imageDetails"
  parameterType="PGReport"
  resultMap="mainImageDetails">
 select a.image_data as mainImageArr FROM pg_main_image WHERE pg_uid = #{pgUid}
</select>

Comment: Above is in my mapper xml file(ibatis). mainImageArr is an byte[] in my pojo class PGReport.

Comment: Does it take long time to execute the query even in sql developer, I suspect that you may not have an index on pg_uid. The mapper you have defined should handle the blob properly.